# Another limit hinting at Riemann sums (but this is a misleading hint)

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\frac{1}{n} {\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{k}{k^2+1}}}}$

Again, this is not a Riemann sum and I have no idea how to find the sum explicitly. The only thing that comes to mind is to compare this series to the harmonic series and deduce that as $n$ approaches $\infty$, this sum is less than $\ln{n}$, so the value of the limit is $0$.

How plausible is that?

Comment: That is definitely the right idea. Try it out!

Comment: And after you do that, see if you can find the limit when the 1/n is replaced by 1/ln(n).

Comment: Well, I would say that the result would be $1$ then, right? Is there another way to approach this problem apart from using the asymptotics?

Comment: Another way is the [Stolz-Cesaro theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz–Cesàro_theorem)